# Clarity 3 upgrade: NullInjectorError on TreeFocusManagerService

Tags: typescript, treeview, angular9, clarity

today I updated my project to Angular9/Clarity3 from Angular8/Clarity2 and navigating the app I noticed some problem that I fixed, but now I'm stuck on a NullInjectorError:

```
    ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[TreeFocusManagerService -> TreeFocusManagerService -> TreeFocusManagerService]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for TreeFocusManagerService!
Error: NullInjectorError: No provider for TreeFocusManagerService!
    at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (core.js:937) [angular]
    at R3Injector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm5/core.js.R3Injector.get (core.js:11565) [angular]
    at R3Injector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm5/core.js.R3Injector.get (core.js:11565) [angular]
    at R3Injector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm5/core.js.R3Injector.get (core.js:11565) [angular]
    at NgModuleRef$1.push../node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef$1.get (core.js:24827) [angular]
    at Object.get (core.js:23063) [angular]
    at getOrCreateInjectable (core.js:3848) [angular]
    at Module.ɵɵdirectiveInject (core.js:14369) [angular]
    at NodeInjectorFactory.ClrTreeNode_Factory [as factory] (clr-angular.js:19067) [angular]
    at getNodeInjectable (core.js:3956) [angular]
    at instantiateAllDirectives (core.js:8407) [angular]
    at createDirectivesInstances (core.js:7774) [angular]
    at Module.ɵɵelementStart (core.js:14518) [angular]
    at FundTypeModelWizardComponent_Template (fund-type-model-wizard.component.html:193) [angular]
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:832) [angular]
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:784) [angular]
    at :4200/polyfills.js:11081:21 [angular]
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:28122) [angular]
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:601) [<root>]
    at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:507) [<root>]
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1671) [<root>]
    at HTMLAnchorElement.globalZoneAwareCallback (zone.js:1697) [<root>]
```

Related template code is:

```
<clr-wizard-page #page1 [clrWizardPageNextDisabled]="pageOneDisabled">
    <ng-template clrPageTitle>Scelta asset</ng-template>
    <clr-tree-node *ngIf="assets">
        Asset
        <ng-template [clrIfExpanded]="true">
            <clr-tree-node *ngFor="let asset of assets" [(clrSelected)]="asset.selected">
                {{asset.description}}
            </clr-tree-node>
        </ng-template>
    </clr-tree-node>
</clr-wizard-page>
```

and here I have also another problem in TS file:

```
this.wizard.navService.goTo(this.wizard.navService.pageCollection.firstPage);
```

this is the log:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'navService' of undefined
    at FundTypeModelWizardComponent.push../src/app/modules/flows/components/fund-type-model/fund-type-model-wizard/fund-type-model-wizard.component.ts.FundTypeModelWizardComponent.initComponentsState (fund-type-model-wizard.component.ts:144)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (fund-type-model-wizard.component.ts:82)
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:192)
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:130)
    at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:76)
    at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:53)
    at Subject.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js.Subject.next (Subject.js:47)
    at FundTypeModelWizardService.push../src/app/modules/flows/services/fund-type-model-wizard.service.ts.FundTypeModelWizardService.openWizard (fund-type-model-wizard.service.ts:16)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (fund-model-customization-grid.component.ts:152)
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:192)
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:130)
    at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:76)
    at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:53)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapSubscriber._next (map.js:41)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:53)
```

but I don't know at this point the two problems are related in some way.

What can I do?? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

try using the complete hierarchy from clarity. I was also getting the same issue and it consumed my half day. Your code should look like

```
<clr-wizard-page #page1 [clrWizardPageNextDisabled]="pageOneDisabled">
    <ng-template clrPageTitle>Scelta asset</ng-template>
       <clr-tree>
          <clr-tree-node *ngIf="assets">
          Asset
           <ng-template [clrIfExpanded]="true">
            <clr-tree-node *ngFor="let asset of assets" [(clrSelected)]="asset.selected">
                {{asset.description}}
            </clr-tree-node>
           </ng-template>
         </clr-tree-node>
       </clr-tree>
</clr-wizard-page>
```

Adding clr-tree tag fixed this issue for me. See if this helps.

Comment: Ok Mishra I completely forgot to put that and I don't know why, I modified the code, tomorrow I will try the upgrade to Angular 9/Clarity 3 again and tell you back what happened. I think it is a good answer.

Comment: @HelloWorld: Did you try above solution? It fixed for me.  You may want to highlight your problem in detail  ?

Comment: Yes, I tired & worked for me. Thanks @AartiMishra. upvoted :)